# Scala FlatSpec Parametrization vs. Spock Parametrization

Tags: scala, groovy, spock, scalatest

Spock is a nice Groovy testing framework which allows easy parametrization like:

```
where:
    user      | userName
    martin    | Martin
    christoph | Christoph
```

etc.

Is there something similar for Scala available?

Comment: You mean like ScalaTest? http://alexandrekieling.com/blog/parameterized-tests-in-the-jvm/ also: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/table_driven_property_checks

Comment: ScalaTest looks ok, though the syntax in spock is nicer. I don't like this 'forall' part.

Comment: Have you looked at Scala's Specs2 framework? It has Datatables which may be what you're looking for https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.6/org.specs2.guide.UseDatatables.html

Comment: @ConorSvensson Looks very good, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Scala Tests have Table Driven property check. 
you can use Table of tuples. where first tuple must match the parameter name and the remaining are the parameterized. For ex:

```
    forAll(Table(("n", "d"), (1, 3)) { (n:Int, d:Int) => {
         //your code goes here
    }
```

You can find the full documentation [here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/table_driven_property_checks)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Added more info on usage of parameter in scala test